# Extracting data from API in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an API that I can use a `POST` request to get some data of it and the API gives me something like this:

```
{    "data":[
      {
         "responsible_admin":"karla",
         "date":1705912059803,
         "userID":68525952,
         "fixedID":50004048,
         "amount":3100
      },
      {
         "responsible_admin":"zuio",
         "date":1705916702819,
         "userID":15988134,
         "fixedID":43081586,
         "amount":1200
      }    ]"..." }
```

and I cannot figure it out how to extract it.

I mean I tried this code to get the data:

```
Future<void> fetchLogs() async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('my.api.com'),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        "u": "admin",
        "pw": "password",
      }),
    );

    final json = jsonDecode(response.body);

    print(json);
  }
```

and it gives me the data I want... but I cannot show it on a `ListView` widget.

It causes some errors.

If you can provide some information for me of how to show this data on a `ListView` Widget, I would be thankful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a data model

```
class DataEntry {
  final String responsibleAdmin;
  final int date;
  final int userID;
  final int fixedID;
  final int amount;

  DataEntry({
    required this.responsibleAdmin,
    required this.date,
    required this.userID,
    required this.fixedID,
    required this.amount,
  });

  factory DataEntry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataEntry(
      responsibleAdmin: json['responsible_admin'],
      date: json['date'],
      userID: json['userID'],
      fixedID: json['fixedID'],
      amount: json['amount'],
    );
  }
}
```

Then update your fetchLogs()

```
Future<List<DataEntry>> fetchLogs() async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://my.api.com'), 
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
      "u": "admin",
      "pw": "password",
    }),
  );

  //you can get you data after decode
  final json = jsonDecode(response.body);

  List<DataEntry> logs = (json['data'] as List)
      .map((dataEntryJson) => DataEntry.fromJson(dataEntryJson))
      .toList();
  return logs;
}
```